# why $("input[id='username']") works and $("#username") won't?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Update**
I guess I was to quick to assume voodoo jquery mystery. I noticed I do use the "username" Id twice and that is the problem. the second username id was added to the page through html code that was injected to the page from php, so I couldn't see it in the source at first..

I'm writing this client side validation jquery code:

```
username = $("#username").val();

if (username.length < 5 || username.length > 15 || !username_regex.test(username)) {
                error += "invalid username\n";
                $(this).find("label[for='username']").css("color", "red");
                $("#username").css("background-color", "#ffc9c9").css("border-color", "red"); //this doesn't work
                // $("input[id='username']").css("background-color", "#ffc9c9").css("border-color", "red");  //this works
            }
```

and the html:

```
  <p><label for="username">Username</label><input id="username" type="text" name="username"/></p>
```

I have several more jquery/html blocks, exactly the same as these above, for password, email, first name etc..

this validation code is part of onsubmit handler and all of the other blocks are working fine: when a field is not met with the validation criteria, the color of it's label turns red and the background color of it's input field turns to #ffc9c9.

the problem is in the username - it's label does turns red, but it's input field does not turns #ffc9c9. I don't see any reason for it not to work, I use the same line:

```
 $("#*input_field_id*").css("background-color", "#ffc9c9").css("border-color", "red");
```

for every one of the other blocks and it works fine for them.

also see that the commented line:

```
$("input[id='username']").css("background-color", "#ffc9c9").css("border-color", "red");
```

does work and solves my need. but it doesn't solves the mystery and I'm trying to figure out why don't the line above work.
also notice that I have debugged with firebug and got expected results, for example:

```
$("#username").attr("name"); // = username, as expected
```

It comes down to this: why `$("input[id='username']")` works when I try to change it's css but `$("#username")` won't  ?

Comment: don't you have any duplicated id's in your html?

Comment: And what are you trying to achieve by this: $(this).find("label[for='username']").css("color", "red"); ? what this points to?

Comment: @ jimmyweb I have this id only once. and the line you mentioned points to the label of the username and paints it red

Comment: no. "this" doesn't point to label.

Comment: oh, i thought tou ment the whole line. "this" points to the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because IDs must be unique and ID selector only selects the first element with a specific ID, you should use classes instead. You will get the same result by using `.getElementById()` method of the `document` object, this is the expected behavior. Attribute selectors work in a different way.

Comment: This field is unique and I'm using the id="username" only in this input field that I mentioned in the html above

Comment: @Ziv What does `$("[id='username']").length` return?

Comment: @undefined I think you're on to something. strangely enough it returns 2. The thing is that I have a common script added to this page that registers onsubmit handler for the log in form, so I use $("#username").. there as well, but that shouldn't interfere should it ? no html in there, so how come I have 2 "username" id's ?

Comment: @Ziv Surely there are 2 elements in the document with that ID, if you want to see the other element you can use `console.log( $("[id='username']") )`.

Comment: mystery solved, I use it in a common external file.. thanks for the length tip

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

```
$("#username").css({'background-color': "#ffc9c9",'border-color': "red"});
```

Answer (score 0):

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GHjLH/) shows #username works. But I had to remove your line that assigns value to error as it seems to fail on that.

Code:

```
 if (username.length < 5 || username.length > 15 || !username_regex.test(username)) {
     $(this).find("label[for='username']").css("color", "red");
     $("#username").css("background-color", "#ffc9c9").css("border-color", "red");
 }
```

ADDED:

If you intialise your error string before the if block, it works:

```
 username = 'aaa';
 error = '';
 if (username.length < 5 || username.length > 15 || !username_regex.test(username)) {
     error += "invalid username\n";
     $(this).find("label[for='username']").css("color", "red");
     $("#username").css("background-color", "#ffc9c9").css("border-color", "red");
 }
```

Comment: @"Frank Fajardo" I did initialize the "error" field, I didn't added to the snippet here as I thought it's pretty obvious and not relevant to the problem I'm facing

Comment: Have you tried running your script on debug? Your code certainly works if I just initialise error before the if block. So it might be work running your code under debug. Sometimes the obvious are not too obvious.

Comment: I did try it on debug, and when querying $("#username") for several things (name, css attribute, ...) it returns expected results

Comment: @Ziv, by 'expected result', do you mean it is getting the input element that has that id?

Comment: yep, but see my updated answer, I had 2 id's and the both had the exact same properties